# Parse table without id in vb.net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parsing

I need to parse items of this table and display it in various `TextBox` controls in VB.NET.

```
<table class="forumline" border="0" width="90%">
    <th colspan="3">Information about ipaddress 173.194.40.144</th>
<tr>
    <td width="15%" align="right" colspan="1" class="row3"valign="top"><p align="center"><b>Provider Info</b></td>
    <td width-"15%" align="center" colspan="1" class="row3">Country Info</td>
    <td width="15%" align="center" colspan="1" class="row3"><b>Time info</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">IP address<br><input type="text" name="T1" size="20" value="173.194.40.144"> </td>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">Country<br><input type="text" name="T2" size="20" value="United States"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">Continent<br><input type="text" name="T3" size="20" value="North America"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="row2" width="15%">Hostname<br><input type="text" name="T4" size="20" value="par10s10-in-f16.1e100.net"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row2" width="15%">Region (code)<br><input type="text" name="T8" size="20" value="California (CA)"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row2" width="15%">Latitude<br><input type="text" name="T12" size="20" value="37.4192"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">Organization<br><input type="text" name="T5" size="20" value="Google"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">City<br><input type="text" name="T9" size="20" value="Mountain View"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">Longitude<br><input type="text" name="T13" size="20" value="-122.0574"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="row2" width="15%">ISP<br><input type="text" name="T7" size="20" value="Google"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row2" width="15%">Areacode<br><input type="text" name="T10" size="20" value="650"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row2" width="15%">Time zone<br><input type="text" name="T14" size="20" value="America/Los_Angeles"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">Flag<br><img src="flags/us.gif"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">Postalcode<br><input type="text" name="T11" size="20" value="94043"></td>
    <td align="center" class="row1" width="15%">GMT offset<br><input type="text" name="T15" size="20" value="-7"></td>
</tr>
```

I get the data (IP address, Country, Continent,...GMT offset) when the user clicks on a button.

I tried to use HtmlAgilityPack, but maybe XPATH is better.  I don't know how to use it when the table does not have an id.  I think I must use `td` name (ex `name="T1"`) for this but how?

```
Private Sub NsButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NsButton1.Click

    Dim url As String = ("http://www.iptrackeronline.com/index.php?ip_address=" & NsTextBox1.Text)
    Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    doc.LoadHtml(url)
    Dim node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
```